Why my web socket server go routine stop?
My websocket server is base on Gorilla websocket.  It has a goroutine listening to clients connection and collect the client connection in a map.  Then broadcast a message to all clients.
It ran for about a day and suddenly it stop for some reasons.  I view my log and here's what is on the log file.  Look like something is crashing and I don't know why is doing that.
2024/05/06 18:27:04 Client connected to endpoint
2024/05/06 18:33:45 {left     <nil> {<nil>}}
2024/05/06 18:33:45 read tcp 127.0.0.1:5123->127.0.0.1:37418: use of closed network connection
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x78 pc=0x637c8a]

goroutine 6 [running]:
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).beginMessage(0x0, 0xc000224510, 0x1)
        /Users/mana/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.5.1/conn.go:492 +0x2a
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).NextWriter(0x0, 0x1)
        /Users/mana/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.5.1/conn.go:535 +0x3f
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).WriteJSON(0x69af80?, {0x69af80, 0xc0001e8770})
        /Users/mana/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/websocket@v1.5.1/json.go:24 +0x34
ws/internal/handlers.broadcastToAll({{0x6b4486, 0x9}, {0x0, 0x0}, {0xc00013ca70, 0x3}, {0xc0000199c8, 0x13}, {0x66cb00, 0xc0001605d0}, ...})
        /Users/mana/dev/go/ws/internal/handlers/handlers.go:116 +0x99
ws/internal/handlers.ListenToWsChannel()
        /Users/mana/dev/go/ws/internal/handlers/handlers.go:150 +0x1b8
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        /Users/mana/dev/go/ws/cmd/web/main.go:13 +0xf3
"message.log" [readonly] 1938L, 148918B 

Here's my handler.go file
package handlers

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sort"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var wsChan = make(chan WsPayload)

var upgradeConnection = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin:     func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}

type SafeClients struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    v  map[WebSocketConnection]string
}


func (sc *SafeClients) Value(key WebSocketConnection) string {
    sc.mu.Lock()
    defer sc.mu.Unlock()
    return sc.v[key]
}


func (su *SafeClients) Add(key WebSocketConnection) {
    su.mu.Lock()
    su.v[key] = ""
    su.mu.Unlock()
}

var clients = SafeClients{v: make(map[WebSocketConnection]string)}

type WebSocketConnection struct {
    *websocket.Conn
}

// WsJsonResponse defines the response sent back from websocket
type WsJsonResponse struct {
    Action         string   `json:"action"`
    Message        string   `json:"message"`
    Userrole       string   `json: "userrole"`
    Etype          string   `json: "etype"`
    Payload        any      `json: "payload"`
    ConnectedUsers []string `json: "connect_users"`
}

type WsPayload struct {
    Action   string              `json: "action"`
    Username string              `json: "username"`
    Userrole string              `json: "userrole"`
    Message  string              `json: "message"`
    Etype    string              `json: "etype"`
    Payload  any                 `json: "payload"`
    Conn     WebSocketConnection `json: "-"`
}

// WsEndpoint upgrades
func WsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ws, err := upgradeConnection.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    log.Println("Client connected to endpoint")

    var response WsJsonResponse
    response.Message = `<em><small>Connected to server</small></em>`

    conn := WebSocketConnection{Conn: ws}
    clients.Add(conn)

    err = ws.WriteJSON(response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    go ListenForWs(&conn)

}

func ListenForWs(conn *WebSocketConnection) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            log.Println("Error", fmt.Sprintf("%v", r))
        }
    }()

    var payload WsPayload

    for {
        err := conn.ReadJSON(&payload)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            conn.Close()
            break
        } else {

            log.Print(payload)
            payload.Conn = *conn
            wsChan <- payload
        }
    }
}

func broadcastToAll(response WsJsonResponse) {
    for client := range clients.v {
        err := client.WriteJSON(response)
        if err != nil {
            _ = client.Close()
            delete(clients.v, client)
        }

    }
}

func ListenToWsChannel() {
    var response WsJsonResponse

    for {
        e := <-wsChan

        switch e.Action {
        case "user":
            clients.Add(e.Conn) // = e.Userrole
        case "message":
            //users := getUserList()
            response.Action = "message"
            response.Message = e.Message
            //response.ConnectedUsers = users
            response.Etype = e.Etype
            response.Userrole = e.Userrole
            response.Payload = e.Payload
            broadcastToAll(response)

        case "left":
            response.Action = "user_left"
            delete(clients.v, e.Conn)
            e.Conn.Close()
            users := getUserList()
            response.ConnectedUsers = users
            broadcastToAll(response)
        }
    }
}

func getUserList() []string {
    var userList []string
    for _, x := range clients.v {
        userList = append(userList, x)
    }
    sort.Strings(userList)
    return userList
}


Start by running your server with the race detector. Your use of SafeClients does not look very safe. The stack trace shows where the panic happened, walk through those calls and see what might be invalid or nil where you don't expect it.
